# How to simplify this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I go by simplifying this: $$\frac{a-b}{2}+\frac{a+b}{3}-\frac{b-a}{4}$$
Also, this: $$\frac{a^2-16^2}{2a+8b}$$

Tried looking around, but letters in equations just fuzzles me.

Comment: Should that $16^2$ be $16b^2$?

Comment: For the first, try putting everything over a common denominator and then adding the numerators. For the second, after Gerry's correction, try factoring the numerator.

Comment: Gerry Myerson, it's 16².

& Jaycob, could you please explain what that means?

Comment: You'd have to type @JaycobColeman to give me a notification. Both have been demonstrated now, but [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/fractions/Equivalent_fractions/v/finding-common-denominators) and [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/multiplying-factoring-expression/Factoring-simple-expressions/v/factoring-and-the-distributive-property-2) do a good job explaining common denominators and factoring I think.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{a-b}{2}+\frac{a+b}{3}-\frac{b-a}{4}=\frac{6(a-b)+4(a+b)-3(b-a)}{12}=$$
$$=\frac{6a-6b+4a+4b-3b+3a}{12}=\frac{13a-5b}{12}$$
and 
$$\frac{a^2-16b^2}{2a+8b}=\frac{a^2-(4b)^2}{2(a+4b)}=\frac{(a-4b)(a+4b)}{2(a+4b)}=\frac{a-4b}{2}$$
and as you ask
$$\frac{a^2-16^2}{2a+8b}=\frac{(a-16)(a+16)}{2(a+4b)}$$

Comment: The second one looks like a complication, not a simplification, to me.

Comment: I don't see where is complication

Comment: It could be said that $(x-y)(x+y)$ is a complication of $x^2-y^2$ in that it requires several more syllables to write.

Comment: I think the question is defective, since OP insist that question I try to answer it but simplification in that case is not possible. As you commented there instead of $16$ must be $16b^2$ (in that case question make sense).

Answer (score 0):

2, 3 and 4 all go into 12. This means that all of the fractions can be written with a denominator of 12.

(a-b)/2=6(a-b)/12,

(a+b)/3=4(a+b)/12 and

(b-a)/4=3(b-a)/12.

After giving them all an equal denominator, they can be added:

6(a-b)/12 + 4(a+b)/12 - 3(b-a)/12

=6(a-b)+4(a+b)-3(b-a)/12

From there, just simplify:

=6(a-b)+4(a+b)+3(a-b)/12

=9(a-b)+4(a+b)/12

=9a-9b+4a+4b/12

=13a-5b/12

Comment: You missed several parentheses. Was that on purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

For the second one, the difference of two squares is used:

a²-b²=(a+b)(a-b)

The question then becomes

(a+4)(a-4)/2a+8b

=(a+4)(a-4)/2(a+4b)

Which is why Gerry asked if it was 16b², because the a+4b would cancel out nicely

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** The first step is to find out the common factor of the denominator. It is obvious that the common factor of $2,3,4$ is $12$. Then given all the fraction below an equal denominator and adding the numerator:

> \begin{align*}
> \\ \frac{a-b}{2}+\frac{a+b}{3}-\frac{b-a}{4} &= \frac{6(a-b)}{12}+\frac{4(a+b)}{12}-\frac{3(b-a)}{12} 
> \\ &= \frac{6(a-b)+4(a+b)-3(b-a)}{12}
> \\ &= \frac{13a-5b}{12}
> \end{align*}

**(2)** For the second one, if we rewrite it as follow. It is obviously that there is not common factors between the nominator and denominator.Hence, $\frac{a^2-16}{2a+8b}$ is already a simplest form.

> $$\frac{a^2-16}{2a+8b}=\frac{(a-4)(a+4)}{2(a+4b)}$$

---

**NOTE** why $16b^2$ is a reasonable guess? Note that $a^2-16b^2 = a^2-(4b)^2=(a-4b)(a+4b)$. Since $(a+4b)$ is a common factor between nominator and denominator, so we can just cancel it out as follow:

> $$\frac{a^2-16b^2}{2a+8b}=\frac{(a-4b)(a+4b)}{2(a+4b)}=\frac{a-4b}{2}$$

Comment: But OP insists it's $16^2$, not $16b^2$.

Comment: Thanks a ton! But as Gerry says, it's 16² not 16b².

Comment: @user1622951 I rewrite my answer. I think the second fraction is already in the simplest form if it is $16^2$, not $16b^2$

Answer (score 0):

Let us separate $a, \; b$
 $$\begin {aligned}\frac{a-b}{2}+\frac{a+b}{3}-\frac{b-a}{4}&=\frac{a}{2}-\frac b2 + \frac{a}{3} +\frac b3-\frac{b}{4} + \frac a4\\
&= a\left(\frac 12+\frac 13 + \frac 14\right)+b\left(-\frac 12 +\frac 13 - \frac 14\right)\\&=a\cdot \frac{13}{12}-b\cdot \frac{5}{12}\\&=\frac{13a-5b}{12}
\end{aligned}$$